# Create a singleton without the object keyword in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, object, singleton

I am wondering if in the following code, a singleton is created without using the object keyword:

```
val a = Comparator<Int>{o1, o2 -> o1.compareTo(o2)}
```

I’ve read the doc. Comparator is an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val a = Comparator<String>{o1, o2 -> o1.compareTo(o2)}
```

is same as

```
val a = object: Comparator<String>{
    override fun compare(o1: String, o2: String): Int {
        return o1.compareTo(o2)
    }
}
```

Both creates instance of anonymous inner class, you cannot create another instance in given execution. You can convert the latter code to lambda because `Comparator` is a functional interface with single abstract function.

> I’ve read the doc. Comparator is an interface.

Yes, it is an interface, but what the above code does is it immediately creates an <strike>singleton</strike> instance of `Comparator`

UPDATE: I had mistakenly considered it a singleton, but as gidds pointed out, a new instance is created for every execution.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I didn't notice that it is a fun interface.

Comment: Won't it create a new instance each time that code gets executed?